# How to change the status code that is recieved in the response in case of specific exceptions in Django rest framework

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework

I am adding some details to my Django model from a react frontend. Everything is working fine and the API request is made with Axios. The data that is being submitted is an OneToOne Field with the user and hence submitting more than once raises an **Integrity error of Unique Constraint**. But the response I receive back has a status of 200. This triggers a notification in my frontend that says details submitted every time the button is pressed. However. that is not being submitted the second time because of the Integrity Error.

My question is if I handle the Integrity Error exception separately how can I send a different status rather than 200 as shown below

```
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data: {message: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: teacher_teacherdetail.user_id'}
headers: {content-length: '39', content-type: 'application/json'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

**Currently I am handling the exception as below**

```
try:
 # some code
    
    except IntegrityError as e:
      
      message = {
       "error": str(e)
      }
      
      return Response(message)
    
    
    except Exception as e:
      
      message = {
        "message": "exception",
        "error": str(e)
      }
      
      return Response(message)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the error.
Here you can find [all valid variables](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/status.py)

```
from rest_framework import status

message = {
    "error": str(e)
}
      
return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```